# Is it possible to retrieve the delete site collection from SharePoint using rest api?

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online, office365api

Is there any rest api or search results will provide the results of **SharePoint deleted site collections**?

It would be  great if i get a help for this.

Thanks,
Kaviya

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to find out if you can recover documents that have been deleted on Sharepoint? Is that what you're asking?

Comment: No, I need to get the deleted site collection.